# How do I incorporate a java SDK in android application development?

Tags: java, android, git, maven, dwolla

I am trying to learn more about DWOLLA, using their sandbox. I am mainly interested in using their access API with an android APPLICATION. The Dwolla API Docs says, "Download and build the JARs to use this library. Maven is required to manage this project's dependencies." The following are the links: 
git clone https://github.com/Dwolla/dwolla-swagger-java
cd dwolla-swagger-java
mvn install package

How do I integrate the above in an android application/project. My assumption is that I would have to do it in gradle but I am not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Android apps' dependencies are managed with [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). 
The default repository is [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter). 
The Dwolla SDK is found [here](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.dwolla%3Adwolla-java-sdk). 
All you have to do is, on that page, click on 'gradle' and you get the line that you have to your app's `build.gradle` file. 
Here it is `compile 'com.dwolla:dwolla-java-sdk:2.0.9'`. 
Add that to your app module's `build.gradle` under `dependencies`, refresh the project and you should be fine.

Comment: @SamuelAlexanderEdelstein No problem. You can accept my answer as the correct one by clicking on the green checkmark next to the voting buttons.